# How to get the current directory the file executed is in using batch of windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm not familiar with this programming language,in PHP it's `getcwd()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand your question but:

The current directory is held in the pseudo-variable %CD%

Getting the directory that the Batch file is located in can be done as follows:

```
%~dp0
```

%0 is the name of the batch file. ~dp gives you the drive and path of the specified argument.